# Alignment between 2 blocks into a navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I am writing a navbar for a website, using Twitter bootstrap. I would like to have the title of the site and the sections of the web site written on the right; so I wrote:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar-left" >
            <H2 class="navbar-text">DISCOTECA</H2>


                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Composers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Genres</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Now this works, but the problem is between the H2 and ul element:
[image: Render of the code above]

How could I put composers and genres a little more down, in order to center them with the word "discoteca"? Thanks for your help

Comment: Post your CSS too please.

Comment: It is the standard twitter bootstrap css:
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in bootstrap css there are two simple CSS one-liners.

One:

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 7px!important;
}
```

Two:

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 33px;
}
```

The first is calculates (manually) margin. The second one is just setting the same `line-height` DISCOTECA has. The second is nicer I think. Though both are not general.

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/z3QPd/2/

Comment: Why are you using !important??? There is no inline styles applied? Just curious if there is a CSS trick here.

Comment: Bootstrap sets a lot of `margin` for `.navbar` and I've been lazy overriding it. I've set more specific selector and now `!important` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Add to your ul.nav class the following css, this is a possible solution there are many btw.

```
  ul.nav {
     position: relative;
     top: 10px; //Or whatever actuall amount you want to add.
     top: 50%; //You can use percentage to get this centered better though.

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS isn't designed for vertical centering, but if you add something like `padding-top: 10px` to your `a` tags you should be able to manually vertically center them with your `h2` header.

Comment: WHAT!!!! Are you serious.... CSS is perfect vertical Alignment... display: inline-block; with vertical-alignment: top;   You just vertically aligned...

Comment: And your still wrong.... position: relative; top: 50%; anything this is applied to is centered... Please stop...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/4fDFW/ I wrote this code yesterday and injected css dynamically using jquery.. But its still css that vertically aligns my text in the center.

Comment: Hey, look man sorry for being a dick but CSS is an art for me and i should be trying to help.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but I was trying to outline the fact that there is no css property that automatically centers a div vertically, like `vertical-align: center` (I know this works in tables). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You cant make cake with just eggs you have to have the right recipe. Thats all that css is, a giant recipe. Mix a few items together to make a tasty cake.